# Value is not updated in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to get the current set of chips in angular material. 
However, when i am removing a chip, the array list of the current chips, is not the updated list when i have to use it.

The chip is removed from the array list when $scope.remove is called, but when i am calling the function loadData(), the list is still the old one containing the removed chips.

```
 var self = this;

        self.selectedScreenNames = [
            {
                'name': 'one'
            },
            {
                'name': 'two'
            }
        ];


        $scope.remove = function(chip) {
            var index = self.selectedScreenNames.indexOf(chip);
            self.selectedScreenNames.splice(index, 0);
        };

        $scope.loadData = function () {
            console.log(self.selectedScreenNames) //This array still contains two values, after the remove has been called
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `splice()` is the number of elements to remove. You're passing 0. So nothing is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Change second argument of `splice` function to 1

```
$scope.remove = function(chip) {
    var index = self.selectedScreenNames.indexOf(chip);
    self.selectedScreenNames.splice(index, 1);
};
```